# About how to hide the view when i press and hold the button

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton

If you press and hold buttonA, you would like to hide viewA
I did this coding.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    //If button A was long pressed
    if gesture.state == .began {
        //I hide viewA.
        self.viewA.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Next, I added buttons and views.
buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD. 
viewA,viewB,viewC,viewD.

I want to hide viewD, for example when I press and hold buttonD.
I thought of the following things.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    ////If buttonA was long pressed
    if gesture.state == .began {
        self.viewA.isHidden = true
    ////If buttonB was long pressed
    } else if gesture.state == .began {
        self.viewB.isHidden = true
    ////If buttonC was long pressed
    } else if gesture.state == .began {
        self.viewC.isHidden = true
    ////If buttonD was long pressed
    } else if gesture.state == .began {
        self.viewD.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to write an if statement.
I know how to hide viewA when I press and hold buttonA.
How should I code when I increase buttons and views?

Answer (score 1):

Ask the `gesture` gesture recognizer for its `view`. That's the view the user is gesturing on (the view to which the gesture recognizer is attached). Now you can work out which view to delete.

Comment: sorry...I do not understand your instructions because my mother tongue is not English.How to ask the gesture gesture recognizer for its view?

Comment: You say `gesture.view`. — This is not a linguistic matter. Just read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624212-view)! (Or learn Swift, if that's what it takes.)